# Correct way to add text over an image in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Once for all I need to learn how to place a text and button over an image using Bootstrap 3. I am trying to hit this result:

[image: Template image]
The website is: [Example of the image](https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/sublime/)

I am thinking the structure is something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/h9pxMmg/home-slider-1.jpg">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="home_slider_content"  data-animation-in="fadeIn" data-animation-out="animate-out fadeOut">
                            <div class="home_slider_title">A new Online Shop experience.</div>
                            <div class="home_slider_subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a ultricies metus. Sed nec molestie eros. Sed viverra velit venenatis fermentum luctus.</div>
                            <div class="button button_light home_button"><a href="#">Shop Now</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I on the correct path regarding the structure of the HTML?

Best regards.

Comment: This isn't really a BS3 question, it's more of a how do I do CSS question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this structure. I use for it my personal use.

```css
.banner{position:relative}
.banner img{width:100%}
.banner .container{position: absolute; left:0; right:0; top:50%; text-align:left; transform:translateY(-50%)}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="banner"> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/h9pxMmg/home-slider-1.jpg">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="home_slider_content"  data-animation-in="fadeIn" data-animation-out="animate-out fadeOut">
   <div class="home_slider_title">A new Online Shop experience.</div>
   <div class="home_slider_subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit. Nullam a ultricies metus. Sed nec molestie eros. Sed viverra
    velit venenatis fermentum luctus.</div>
   <div class="button button_light home_button"><a href="#">Shop Now</a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. I am not quite getting how I place the text like on the example page. I have to set a padding on each text or?

Comment: If you use Bootstrap so you don't have to add padding on both sides. in bootstrap, container have its width:1170px; and margin:0 auto. so it will always be center. Updated the Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you again. So I am quite close to the goal now. But I am not quite sure why the text is not responsive? Try to see the example on a smaller viewpoint. I have to make media queries to control that? I thought that was in the past? https://jsfiddle.net/zc97k1jn/

Comment: Yes, You have to add media queries for your viewports. Populars like 1299, 991, 767, 639. But you can add it how you need.